# Merge two Linked List In c++ without using inbuilt sort method

Tags: c++, sorting, struct, merge, linked-list

You are given two linked lists the thing is that one of them is sorted and the other isn't the task is that you have to merge them and sort their value while comparing during execution not sorting both linked lists separately and also without using any inbuilt method from c++ template library.

I have attempted the question by myself but it isn't working. I think it is approaching an infinite loop condition in the if condition!

This is what I have done:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct Student {
    int id;
    Student *next = NULL;
};
Student *first = NULL;
Student *last = NULL;
Student *first2 = NULL;
Student *last2 = NULL;

void display(Student *k);

void insert_end(Student *k);

void merge();

int main() {
    int exit = 1;
    do {
        cout << "11.Display, 12.Insert, 3.Merge\n";
        cout << "21.Display, 22.Insert, 0:exit\n";
        cin >> exit;
        switch (exit) {
            case 11:
                display(first);
                break;
            case 12:
                insert_end(last);
                break;
            case 3:
                // first = mergeTwoLists(first, first2);
                //merge();
                Student* SortedMerge(Student* a, Student* b);
                break;
            case 21:
                display(first2);
                break;
            case 22:
                insert_end(last2);
                break;
            default:
                cout << "WRONG\n";
                break;
        }
    } while (exit != 0);
    return 0;
}

void display(Student *k) {
    Student *p = k;
    while (p != NULL) {
        cout << "ID: " << p->id << "\n";
        p = p->next;
    }
}

void insert_end(Student *k) {
    cout << "This is the function of insert_end \n";
    Student *current = new Student;
    cout << "Enter ID: ";
    cin >> current->id;
    if (k == NULL) {
        if (k == last) {
            first = last = current;
        } else {
            first2 = last2 = current;
        }
    } else {
        if (k == last) {
            last->next = current;
            last = current;
        } else {
            last2->next = current;
            last2 = current;
        }
    }
}
void merge() {
    Student *p1 = first;
    Student *p2 = first2;
    while (p1 != NULL) {
        p2 = first2;
      while (p2->next != NULL) {
            if (p1->id <= p2->id) {
                Student *curr = p2;
                curr->next = p1->next;
                p1->next = curr;
            }
            p2 = p2->next;
        }
        p1 = p1->next;
    }
}
```

What could be the possible optimized solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at first to rewrite the function `insert_end`. Initially the both pointers last and last2 are null pointers

```
Student *first = NULL;
Student *last = NULL;
Student *first2 = NULL;
Student *last2 = NULL;
```

So if the user will decide at first to fill the second list then due to this if statement

```
if (k == NULL) {
    if (k == last) {
        first = last = current;
    } else {
        first2 = last2 = current;
    }
}
```

the function will insert a new node in the first list instead of the second list.

The function `merge` is also wrong. For starters it changes neither `first` nor `first2` and neither `last` and `last2`.

If the if statement

```
if (p1->id <= p2->id) {
    Student *curr = p2;
    curr->next = p1->next;
    p1->next = curr;
}
```

gives the control then the data member `next` of the pointer `p2` is changed due to these lines

```
    Student *curr = p2;
    curr->next = p1->next;
```

that is the data member `next` of the pointer of the second list points to the node of the first list.

But then after the if statement

```
p2 = p2->next;
```

the pointer `p2` points to a node in the first list instead of pointing to a node in the second list.

To make the life easier you need to define one more structure as for example

```
struct List
{
    struct Student *first;
    struct Student *last;
};
```

and define the functions for pointers of this structure type.